# Mariadb: Regexp_substr not working with non-matching group regular expression

Tags: regex, mariadb

I am using a query to pull a user ID from a column that contains text. This is for a forum system I am using and want to get the User id portion out of a text field that contains the full message. The query I am using is

`SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(message,  '(?:member: )(\d+)'
) AS user_id
from posts
where message like '%quote%';`

Now ignoring the fact thats ugly SQL and not final I just need to get to the point where it reads the user ID. The following is an example of the text that you would see in the message column

```
`QUOTE="Moony, post: 967760, member: 22665"]I'm underwhelmed...[/QUOTE]

Hopefully we aren’t done yet and this is nothing but a depth signing!`
```

Is there something different about the regular expression when used in mariadb REGEXP_SUBST? this should be PCRE and works within regex testers and should read correctly. It should be looking for the group "member: " and then take the numbers after that and have a single match on all those posts.

Comment: I am not following why you're grouping  the string `member:`, noncapturing as it may be.

Comment: It seems you want `'(?<=member: )\d+'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `(?<=member: )\d+` provides the same outcome, which is null. Both your regexp and mine works if I test it on https://regex101.com/ but not once it is inside the SQL query

Comment: @DanFarrell I am grouping it as it seems the most logical search grouping to identify that group of numbers, as I can't rely on the position being consistent

Answer (score 0):

This is an ugly hack/workaround that works by using a lookahead for the following `"]` however will not work if there are multiple quotes in a post

`(?<=member: )\.+(?="])`